# I am currently reading Eloquent JavaScript and I'm trying to solve the recursion test, but my code keeps giving me an 'undefined' feedback

Tags: javascript

This is the sample of my code:

```js
Function isEven(number) {
 (number == 1) {
return false;
}
else if (number == 0) {
return true;
}
else {
number += 2;
return isEven(-number);
}
};
```

This is the result I keep getting:
Console.log(isEven(50)); // undefined

Comment: You have more than a few syntax problems. Your code does not return `undefined` at the moment, it throws a SyntaxError.

Comment: under function isEven, next line states: (number == 1) { .... I think it should be with " if ".. Like: if (number == 1) {

Answer (score 1):

Try using;

```js
function isEven(number) {
 if(number == 1) {
   return false;
}
else {
if (number == 0) {
  return true;
}
else {
 number -= 2;
 return isEven(number);
}
}
}
console.log(isEven(50));
```

You had a lot of syntax error as well as logical error. Note this logic only works for positive number. Hope it helps.